# Replacing consecutive non-space elements less than a specified length

Tags: python, string

I have a python string

```
'AAAAA     BBB      AAAAA   AA     BBBBBB'
```

with the blank spaces in between.

I need the output to have the non zero islands below a certain length to be replaced by blank spaces.

Say for example I need to replace strings smaller than 4 characters long, then my output should look like:

```
'AAAAA              AAAAA          BBBBBB'
```

with the position of other characters being the same.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yet? We can help much better when there is code already.

Comment: Read substrings and their lengths. If substring is smaller than 4 characters long, replace it with character length many spaces. Ignore spaces while reading.

Comment: Your example happens to use *matching characters* in each group. Must the consecutive letters be the same for them to be considered an 'island'?

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression, using the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}\b', lambda m: ' ' * len(m.group()), inputstring)
```

The `3` is your maximum number of consecutive characters.

Breaking this down:

- [`re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) will find matches in `string` using `pattern`, then uses the `replacement` pattern or function to produce replacements, and a new string is returned.
- The pattern `\b\w{1,3}\b` uses.

  - `\b` word boundaries; these match *between* word and non-word characters or at the start or end; here between a space and a letter. By putting these at either end of `\w` means we only want matches that have spaces or the start or end of the string on each side.
  - `\w` matches 'word' characters, which are letters and digits and underscores.
  - `{n,m}` states a pattern must be repeated between *n* and *m* times; you can leave one or the other out for *none* or *as many as you like*. `{1,3}` means between 1 and 3 times a character that matches `\w`.
- The replacement is a function, that is passed a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) for each matching substring. Here, it returns a number of spaces matching the input string length.

See the [*Regular Expression HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) for more info.

If you want to keep the length variable, use formatting to add the number into the pattern:

```
def blank_out_up_to(string, length):
    return re.sub(
        rf'\b\w{{1,{length}}}\b',
        lambda m: ' ' * len(m.group()), 
        string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> example = 'AAAAA     BBB      AAAAA   AA     BBBBBB'
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...     print(f'{i}: {blank_out_up_to(example, i)}')
...
1: AAAAA     BBB      AAAAA   AA     BBBBBB
2: AAAAA     BBB      AAAAA          BBBBBB
3: AAAAA              AAAAA          BBBBBB
4: AAAAA              AAAAA          BBBBBB
5:                                   BBBBBB
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation using `re`,

```
inp = 'AAAAA     BBB      AAAAA   AA     BBBBBB'

''.join([x if len(x) > 3 else ' ' * len(x) for x in re.split(r'(\s+)', inp)])

>> 'AAAAA              AAAAA          BBBBBB'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an anti-regex solution using `itertools`.

This works if, as in your example, your groups consist of identical characters. If this is not guaranteed, you should use a regex method.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

x = 'AAAAA     BBB      AAAAA   AA     BBBBBB'

res = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(i if len(i)>3 else ' '*len(i) for i in
                                  (''.join(j) for _, j in groupby(x))))

print(res)
# "AAAAA              AAAAA          BBBBBB"
```

Comment: Note that this will only group identical characters. The OP didn't specify, but it's possible that something like `AABB` should be considered a single group of 4 characters. In that case you'll have to pass a key function like `str.isspace` or something similar to `groupby`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Sure, I added a disclaimer. Hopefully, OP returns to provide clarification.